# Attempt at SSIS Execution Throws Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I can run the SSIS package in SSMS 2014 if I set the build to SQL Server 2012, but attempting to run in SSMS 2017 v17.4 gives this error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)"

There is little info out there as to a fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup SSISDB database from SSMS 2014.
2. Create Integration Service catalog on SSMS 2017 and restore backup.
3. Change the SSISDB database owner sa.
4. Right click on SSISDB under Integration Service Catalogs.
5. Select Database Upgrade-> Select Next -> Select I have taken backup of the SSISDB database. continue with the SSISDB upgrade and Select Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing SSISDB Database, 
Then Integration Services Catalog -> (Right click) Create New Catalog

Comment: Do u mean to delete catalogue or database ?

Comment: It's Database, Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

1. Create the SSISDB Catalog on 2017.
2. Once the SSISDB database is created automatically.
3. Script the missing objects from the SQL Version 2017.
   Table - SSISDB.internal.customized_logging_levels
   View - SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels
   Stored procedures -
   set_customized_logging_level_value
   set_customized_logging_level_description
   rename_customized_logging_level
   delete_customized_logging_level
   create_customized_logging_level
4. Restore the SSISDB database from the backup of SQL Server 2014.
5. Change the SSISDB database owner sa.
6. Create the above scripted objects.